# Highcharts change color of Pie slices

Tags: html, highcharts, colors, datatables

Update:

I was able to get the percentage to show and also a legend. But still not able to change colors.

```
chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        styledMode: true
    },
    tooltip: {
         pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    theme: {
          colors: [
                    'green',
                    'red',
                    'fushcia'
                  ]
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          colors: [
                    'green',
                    'red',
                    'fushcia'
                  ],
                     allowPointSelect: true,
                     cursor: 'pointer',
                     dataLabels:  {
                     enabled: false
                     },
                   showInLegend: true
           }

    },
    title: {
        text: 'Rundeck Jobs Stats'
    },
    series: [
        {
            data: chartData(table)
        }
```

Original Post :

I have a Pie chart generated from a HTML table with DataTables. I am looking at one column, STATUS, that shows either succeeded, failed or aborted. The chart is counting the number of occurrences of each and draws a Pie.

I would like the pie chart to be green for the successes, red for the failures and fushcia for the aborted.

I also would like the slices to show their respective percentages of the pie.

this is the code I have for creating the chart, it is taken directly from the example at https://datatables.net/examples/api/highcharts.html

```
    // Create DataTable
const table = new DataTable('#example');
 
// Create chart
const chart = Highcharts.chart('demo-output', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        styledMode: true
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Rundeck Jobs Stats'
    },
    series: [
        {
            data: chartData(table)
        }
    ]
});
 
// On each draw, update the data in the chart
table.on('draw', function () {
    chart.series[0].setData(chartData(table));
});
 
function chartData(table) {
    var counts = {};
 
    // Count the number of entries for each position
    table
        .column(3, { search: 'applied' })
        .data()
        .each(function (val) {
            if (counts[val]) {
                counts[val] += 1;
            }
            else {
                counts[val] = 1;
            }
        });
 
    return Object.entries(counts).map((e) => ({
        name: e[0],
        y: e[1]
    }));
}
```

I've looked at a number of posts and tried to add colors to the series but no joy as of yet.

thanks in advance

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using `styledMode`:

> **styledMode: boolean**
>
> Whether to apply styled mode. When in styled mode, no presentational
> attributes or CSS are applied to the chart SVG. Instead, CSS rules are
> required to style the chart. The default style sheet is available from
> https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css.

You can disable it as below or style your chart in CSS.

```
chart: {
  ...,
  styledMode: false
}
```

---

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hm5nb2o4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.styledMode

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the links. I copied and pasted your code for create chart into my page. I see the legend uses those colors, but the graph for some reason, does not, even tho I see in your example that the graph IS using the colors. It is using default pastels Did u alter the CSS or something. . Also notices that whatever value is in the first row, gets that color ... so succeeded isnt always green etc. ... Still Investigating

Comment: Just noticed you are not loading the highcharts CSS. I took that out and now my Pie chart has the colors So thanks very much for that. I still see that the colors are not fixed to the data. Trying to get green always succeeded, red failure etc.

Comment: Hi@Roger McCarrick, in this case, you need to set the color directly on data points. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sk7awrbg/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data.color

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I took a look at the example you gave, but it is creating a new slice for every row in the table instead of group them into the categories of Succeeded, Failed and Aborted.

Comment: So, you want to have three slices, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8jLuot3r/